# Range of $f(x) = | x-1| + |x - a| + | x| + |x+1| + |x+ 2a - 21|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The Range of function $f(x) = | x-1| + |x - a| + | x| + |x+1| + |x+ 2a - 21|$ is

where $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: The 21 seems unlikely

Comment: Hint: the range is of the form $[\min f,+\infty)$.

Comment: Yes answer given is $\left[min f,\infty \right)$ but how can i calculate it, Thanks

Comment: You can pick some $a$ of interest and graph the thing. The values of $a$ where behavior changes are those which cause two of the absolute value quantities to agree, so $a \in \{0,1,-1,7,21/2,   \}$ various others I guess. The minimum of $f$ should be continuous in $a$ and, I imagine, piecewise linear as well. Draw some pictures.

Comment: @WillJagy Actually, one can prove that the minimum is attained at one of the values that annihilate one of the absolute values. Can you see a clever way to determine which one is the minimum then? Without distinguishing too many cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, one should observe that the function $f$ is $+\infty$ at $\pm \infty$.
It follows that $f$ attains a minimum and
$$
f(\mathbb{R})=[\min f,+\infty).
$$

Note next that $f$ is differentiable everywhere but at $1, a, 0, -1, 21-2a$.

Assume that $f$ attains its minimum somewhere out of these critical points. Then the derivative there must be zero. But the derivative would be of the form
$$
\pm 1+\pm 1+\pm 1+\pm 1+\pm 1.
$$
Since there are $5$ terms, this can never make $0$.

So the minimum is one of the values
$$
f(1),f(a),f(0),f(-1),f(21-2a).
$$

Now I can't see anything more clever than computing these values and distinguish cases.

**Edit:** See Ross Millikian's comment below. There is indeed a more clever way to approach the last step. Basically, the minimum is attained at $x_0$, where $x_0$ is in the mid value among the five values $-1,0,1$ and $a,21-2a$. Note that you have to be more careful when these collapse to $4$ values (when $a=-1,0,1,7, ...$).

Remark: It is not hard to see, more generally, that a linear combination with positive coefficcients of functions of the type $|ax+b|$ attains its minimum at one of the values that annihilate the $|ax+b|$'s. You just have to observe that such a function is piecewise affine with possible change of slope at these specific values.

Comment: At large negative $x$ the slope is $-5$ while at large positive $x$ the slope is $+5$.  Each time you cross one of the points going right, the slope increases by $2$.  So the one you want for the minimum is the middle one.  If $a$ is large (of either sign) that will be $0$, but if $a$ is $\frac 12$ it will be $a$ and if $a$ is $\frac 32$ it will be $1$.

Comment: @RossMillikan I knew I had missed a key observation... Thanks! Just a remark: for $a=0$, for instance, we end up with a $2|x|$ term so the slope increses by $4$ at $0$ and the minimum is $f(0)$. So I am afraid there are still a few cases to consider.

Comment: Thanks julien and Ross Millikan